# minimal DFA transition function clearification

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, finite-automata

**Statement:**

Given any dfa $M$, application of the procedure 'reduce' (see below) yields another dfa $\hat{M}$ such that $M$ and $\hat{M}$ are equivalent. Furthermore $\hat{M}$ is minimal in the sense that there is no other dfa with a smaller number of states that also accepts $L(M)$

**First some background information:**

The 'reduce' procedure:

Given a dfa $M=\left(Q, \Sigma, \delta, q_{0}, F\right)$, we construct a reduced dfa $\widehat{M}=(\widehat{Q}, \Sigma, \widehat{\delta}, \widehat{q}, \widehat{F})$ as follows.

1. Use procedure mark to generate the equivalence classes, say $\left\{q_{i}, q_{j}, \ldots, q_{k}\right\}$, as described.
2. For each set $\left\{q_{i}, q_{j}, \ldots, q_{k}\right\}$ of such indistinguishable states, create a state labeled $i j \ldots k$ for $\widehat{M}$.
3. For each transition rule of $M$ of the form
   $$
   \delta\left(q_{r}, a\right)=q_{p},
   $$
   find the sets to which $q_{r}$ and $q_{p}$ belong. If $q_{r} \in\left\{q_{i}, q_{j}, \ldots, q_{k}\right\}$ and $q_{p} \in\left\{q_{l}, q_{m}, \ldots, q_{n}\right\}$, add to $\widehat{\delta}$ a rule
   $$
   \widehat{\delta}(i j \cdots k, a)=l m \cdots n .
   $$
4. The initial state $\widehat{q}_{0}$ is that state of $\widehat{M}_{\text {}}$ whose label includes the 0 .
5. $\widehat{F}$ is the set of all the states whose label contains $i$ such that $q_{i} \in F$.

**A claim in order to prove the statement:**

Take any state $q \in Q$ and let $\hat{q}$ denote its equivalence class. For any word $w \in \Sigma^{*}$, it holds that $\delta^{*}(q, w) \in \hat{\delta}^{*}(\hat{q}, w)$. The proof is by induction on the length $n$ of $w$.
base case If $n=0$, then $w=\lambda$ and the claim is trivial since
$$
\delta^{*}(q, \lambda)=q \in \hat{q}=\hat{\delta}^{*}(\hat{q}, \lambda) .
$$
For the induction step assume our claim holds for all strings of length $n-1$ we show that it shows for strings of length $n$. In this case $w=a v$ for some $v$. We know that
$$
\begin{array}{rlr}
\delta^{*}(q, w) & =\delta^{*}(q, a v) \\
& =\delta^{*}(\delta(q, a), v) & \text { definition of } \delta^{*} \\
& \in \hat{\delta}^{*}(\widehat{\delta(q, a)}, v) & \text { induction hypothesis } \\
& =\hat{\delta}^{*}\left(\hat{\delta}^{}(\hat{q}, a), v\right) \\
& =\hat{\delta}^{*}(\hat{q}, w) \\
\end{array}
$$

**My question:**

In the proof of the claim above, I do not know how we can be sure that

$ \widehat{\delta(q, a)} = \hat{\delta}^{}(\hat{q}, a)$

It seems trivial, but shouldn't it be proven?

Source: *Formal languages and automata* by Peter Linz, 5th edition (Jones & Bartlett Learning), p. 75

Comment: Books have authors and publishers. They often go through multiple editions, each with a date. Quotes are taken from a particular page in a particular edition of a particular book, and a citation must include this information. I guessed which book you're talking about, but you need to fill in the rest. This is mandatory, not just by [the rules of this site](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), but also to comply with copyright rules and academic practice. Thanks.

Comment: @rici I updated the question, thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $ \widehat{\delta(q, a)} = \hat{\delta}^{}(\hat{q}, a)$

The equality above is the definition of $\hat\delta$, given $\delta$. Let us paraphrase item 3.

> 3. For each transition rule of $M$ of the form
>    $$
>    \delta(q, a)=\delta(q, a),
>    $$
>    find the sets to which $q$ and $\delta(q, a)$ belong. If $q \in\hat q$ and $\delta(q, a)\in\widehat{\delta(q, a)} $, add to $\widehat{\delta}$ a rule
>    $$
>    \hat{\delta}(\hat q, a)= \widehat{\delta(q, a)}.
>    $$

---

On the other hand, there is an important question: why is $\delta$ well-defined? Suppose $q_i\in \hat q$ and $q_j\in \hat q$, then $\hat{\delta}(\hat q, a)$ is defined as $\widehat{\delta(q_i,a)}$ as well as $\widehat{\delta(q_j,a)}$. Are $\widehat{\delta(q_i,a)}$ and $\widehat{\delta(q_j,a)}$ the same equivalence class?

This well-defined-ness is a key step in the 'reduce' procedure. I will leave it for you to verify.

Comment: Thank you very much! About the question in your answer: Suppose that the transitions resulted in different equivalence classes, that would mean that δ(qi,a) and δ(qj,a) are distinguishable. Suppose they are distinguishable by a string of length n, then qi and qj would be distinguishable by a string of length n+1 and so they wouldn’t be in the same equivalence class (contradiction). Is this a correct reasoning and answer to the question?

Comment: And I can't edit the answer because my edit is too small, but I think you made a little mistake in the question: "is defined as ˆδ(qi,a) as well as ˆδ(qi,a)" so two times qi instead of qi and qj.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.